# How do I pass my data into google charts api?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am having trouble getting the values of my variables to pass to the var data portion of the drawchart function using `google charts api`. As is, my code currently displays the title of the chart, but no actual chart. If I change my data to be fixed numbers `(1,2,3,4)` instead of `(h,i,j,k)` then I get a chart exactly as I want. The problem is the data for the chart is not fixed. Any help would be great.

```
script type="text/javascript">
var h;
var i;
var j;
var k;

function myFunction() {
// h,i,j,k are calculated in here.   
};


  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  //i now reference h,i,j,k in the var data portion of the drawchart function
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['P&I',     h],
      ['Tax',      i],
      ['Insurance',  j],
      ['MI', k]
    ],
    false);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      pieHole: 0.4,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried passing in the values of the numbers as strings to the chart (putting them inside of single quotes)

Comment: What do you mean by data is not fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with timing.
When do you call `myFunction`?

This works...

```js
var h;
var i;
var j;
var k;

function myFunction() {
  // h,i,j,k are calculated in here.   
  h = 2;
  i = 4;
  j = 6;
  k = 8;
};


google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  
  // set var values
  myFunction();
  
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['P&I',        h],
    ['Tax',        i],
    ['Insurance',  j],
    ['MI',         k]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'My Daily Activities',
    pieHole: 0.4,
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="donutchart" style="height: 320px; width: 320px;"></div>
```